# How to put labels and separators in a matlab graph

Tags: matlab, graph

I have a graph which shows the data from an accelerometer in the three axis with the time as follows

```
M_acc(:,1) = X_Axis_acc;
M_acc(:,2) = Y_Axis_acc;
M_acc(:,3) = Z_Axis_acc;

figure
set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize')); % Maximize figure.
plot(time_acc,M_acc);
xlabel('Time[s]','FontSize', 15);
ylabel('Value[deg/s]','FontSize', 15);
h = legend('location','best','X-Axis', 'Y-Axis', 'Z-Axis');
set(h, 'FontSize', 15);
title('Accelerometer')
```

I also have the list of points i want to put the separator, with the label as:

```
M_ant(:,1) = t_start;
M_ant(:,2) = t_stop;
M_ant(:,3) = State;
```

What I want is having the figure instead of the following:

[image: Graph I have]

something similar to this:

[image: Graph I want]

Is possible something similar?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more because I don't understand what the black lines and numbers represent on the graph that you want. And what is M_ant exactly? I don't understand the sentence points "i want to put the separator, with the label as".

Comment: @Tina What I want is to put the black lines and the numbers with the .m file, The M_ant contains the times of separation, the vertical black lines, called t_start and t_stop, and the label, the number below the black lines, is the State contained in M_ant. The sentence "i want to put the separator, with the label as" means that the times for the separators are t_start and t_stop and the label is State

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`text`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) to display a label and the combination of [`hold on`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html?s_tid=doc_ta) and [`plot`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?s_tid=doc_ta) to add the separators as follows:

```
% Create random data with peaks at 30 and 60
X = rand(100, 1);
X(30) = -1;
X(60) = -2;

% generate the plot separators and labels
figure
plot(X);
hold on
plot([20 20 70 70], [X(20) -3 -3 X(70)], 'k', 'LineWidth', 3)
plot([30 30], [X(30) -3], 'k', 'LineWidth', 3)
text(25,-2.9,'1')
plot([60 60], [X(60) -3], 'k', 'LineWidth', 3)
text(45,-2.9,'2')
text(65,-2.9,'3')
```

[image]